# Conversion of an OSM Multipolygon to a Shapefile Polygon Using QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert

I am quite new to the topic of handling geodata, so I face my first big challenge now:

I downloaded an osm file containing information about any kind of data related to power generators, transformer stations etc. (http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/wiki/Extracting_Power_Data_from_OpenStreetMap). I successfully loaded this file to QGIS, where I started using the `save as` option to simply save it as a shapefile. This worked fine for points and lines, but not for multipolygons and multilines. As I think I know now it´s because shapefiles do not support these types (correct?). So I tried an advice from our forum to use the geometry tool multi to onepart. But now when I try this I get the error

> **len**() should return >= 0 See log for more details

Has anybody faced the same problem? My overall goal here is just to use this dataset as a shapefile.

Update: Maybe also an relevant information is that the properties of the layer display "Number of objects in this layer: -1"

Comment: Shapefile supports multipolygon, but the export will fail if the source data has geometry errors like self-intersecting or zero-length arcs. So you better check that before.

Answer (score 1):

In editing mode select "Edit -> Split parts"

[image]

In batch mode in geoprocessing toolbar search filed print "part" and select "Multipart to singleparts" tool.

[image]

Also it worth using some database like SpatiaLite or GeoPackage. The ESRI Shape files have numerous limitations and are very ancient GIS format.

Comment: Unfortunately the option split parts is not available for me to choose, do you have an idea why?

Comment: Do you enable editing (see pen icon in buildings on my screenshot) and select this layer in Layer tree?

Comment: The edit pen is also greyed out - maybe there is an error in the file itself?

Comment: This format is read-only. Export to some editing capable format and then edit it.

Comment: I tried to export the file to SpatialLite - I got the error the saved file has no layers. I also tried to export it to geopackage and here the files had only a few KBs size although they should be around a few hundred MBs

Comment: This is not a QGHIS problem. It seems to me the new question needed with your data attached. Here it is the off topic.